# Functions: find a+d

Tags: functions

Problem:
If $f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$, $abcd\neq0$ and $f(f(x))=x$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$, what is the value of $a+d$.

I have tried plugging in $f(x)$ as $x$ into $f(x)$ and setting it equal to $x$, but that only ends up simplifying as $a(ax+b)+bd=dx(cx+d)$ and that doesn't seem to be going anywhere. Can someone please give me a hint (NOT THE ANSWER) to the correct method or where I am going wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need the fact that $f(f(0))=0$ and that $f(y)=0$ gives $y =-\frac b a$.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to solve for $a=-d$ which mean $a+d=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(f(x))=x \implies f^{-1}(x) = f(x)$

$x = \frac{ay+b}{cy+d}$

solve for $y.$

$y = f^{-1}(x) = f(x)$

This should clearly point to what values $a,b,c,d$ can take on.